# Designing a filter by setting an objective

Tags: emi-filtering, passive-filter

In my case I am working on passive analog filters, but I think the question applies to any other type of analog filter design.  Typically I think the process for designing analog filters is to calculate the desired components using equations, or perhaps if we're with a large company we might use filtershop.  We will then plot the frequency response to make sure we did the calculations correctly and that's the end of it.

That process is usually fine, but I wonder if it is possible to do this like excel solver does with the objective cell function.  For example, if I wanted to find the values for a circuit that has a certain gain at a certain frequency, is it possible to run through the infinite number of possible component values to achieve this objective?  It could be in spice, matlab, whatever.

Comment: You just want a first order passive filter? While designed for active filters the TI FilterPro Desktop application is free and can be set to give a 1st order design. In that situation it generates a passive filter with an op-amp buffering the output. If you then change one component value it updates the others to maintain the same frequency response.

Comment: No not 1st order, more specifically I am working with but not limited to pi, LC type filters, as well as some circuits where maybe there are not a set of design equations readily available.  In those cases I would rather work backwards, starting with the objective and then obtaining the component values.  I can obtain the transfer function of these circuits, but the transfer function doesn't allow me to quickly find component values to meet a specific objective.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your certain gain and frequency you want to achieve.  Then, you would either set the value of a resistor, capacitor, or inductor depending on what type of filters you are trying to achieve.  If it is a first-order system with only a resistor and either a capacitor or an inductor, you can pick typical resistor values and enter them in a column.  Plug the numbers in for the specific type of filter you want and the capacitor value will be given to you.

You will have to design the spreadsheet so that you have low-pass filter, high-pass filter, bandpass filter, and bandstop filter equations.

You would have to be more specific about exactly which program you are trying to use to achieve this.  But Excel can work very well to calculate those numbers.  Then simply reproduce in PSPICE, MatLab, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to the slope or rate of change of gain/attenuation and phase rate of change  or group delay in filters.  Yes there are many ways to compute different types and determine tolerance sensitivity, but there are also too many types of filter to consider without constraints on passive vs active, number of reactive elements, and realizable component values with Q or SRF limitations.

**Thus your request is too broad.**  Would you like 1 dB ripple Chebychev band-pass and band-stop thresholds or Cauer or Raised Cosine response or critically damped Butterworth with gravy?  ;)

TI's tool allows you to define new filters in addition to the 5 types given.

Perhaps TI was limited by patent infringements on other software packages as there are other Math software packages around with filter designs.  Ask TI's forum for other types if this interests you.

But you got it right to define an objective before starting a filter design.  Just make sure you include all the factors for realization and effects on S/N Ratio, inter-symbol interference (ISI) jitter, stop band attenuation and component tolerances.

Answer (score 0):

I created a free Computer-Aided-Engineering (CAE) App called "Match-n-freq" ( goal-driven.net/apps/match-n-freq.html) that allows a user to define their passband, stopband, & equal ripple in stopband requirements.  This electrical filter was to make an isolated pulse more symmetric and slimmer.  The more symmetrical and slimmer a pulse, would help minimize the "Pattern-Induced-BitShift" (PIB).